# Bouyancy of ozone gas

Tags: atmospheric-science, ideal-gas, fluid-statics, buoyancy, molecules

If ozone is $O_3$ why is it an outer layer of the atmosphere? It seems $O_3$ would sink in a solution of $O_2$, rather than float on it.

Answer (score 4):

O3 is less stable compared to O2 ( Positive gibbs free energy) . In the upper layers of atmosphere it is constantly generated by UV radiation falling on O2 gas , thus though it dissociates into O2 , it is continuously being generated also. As we come down , rate of generation falls and hence O3 concentration falls too.If O3 tries to fall it will decompose to give O2.